# How to make function template, which takes std::vector and pointer to function?

Tags: c++, templates

Function1 takes pointer to std::vector (unspecified type) and pointer to other function template (Function2). Function2 takes two objects (type like std::vector type) and return bool. How to make these templates?

For Example:

```
bool Function2(int i1, int i2);

void Function1(std::vector<int>* v1, Function2);
```

I try:

```
template <typename type> bool FunctionP(type, type);
template <typename tVector> void FunctionT(tVector* pVector, FunctionP pFunkcja);
```

It gives:

```
'FunctionP' is not a type
```

Comment: Why I got '-1'? Something is unclear? Please tell me.

Comment: Did you try something? If it didn't work, what errors did you get?

Comment: [Add this information to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33467037/edit) please, not as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
bool Function2(int a, int b)

template <typename T>
void Function1(std::vector<T>* vector, std::function < bool(T, T)> callback)
```

call with specializations

```
std::vector<int> vec{1,2,3,4,5};

Function1<int>(&vec, std::bind(Function2, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this caused by the line

```
template <typename tVector> void FunctionT(tVector* pVector, FunctionP pFunkcja);
```

`FunctionP` is a template of a function. You can only store pointers to specializations of template functions, but not the actual template.

So just use the normal pointers as an argument. e.g.

```
bool Function2(int i1, int i2);

void Function1(std::vector<int>* v1, bool (*f)(int, int));
```

Comment: So must I specialize template with every type, what I want to use in vector and function?